# Advanced database Synchronisation using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have to **synchronise my local database in my phone to the server database**. I have a scenario here. Please help me.

A table contains 3 fields - Id, Name, Address.

The user is not connected to the Internet.
The user changes the address for a given id at the phone. 
The admin changes the Name of the same record in the server.

When, the user comes online and synchronises the table, the Name changed by the user should be updated in the server **without affecting the altered address and vice versa.**

I have referred this link. https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync It is good. But still this does not satisfy my need for field update.
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why it did not meet your needs? Do you have some code which does not work?

Comment: I don not have a code. Thats why i am here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to create tables on either side holding information (including fieldname and other data your synchronization demands) about updates done, when they are not connected. And sync them when connection is established